out of inotify watches on startup
When I do a clean reboot and launch qpwgraph or wireplumber, I get an inotify out of watches error.
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches indicates that I have 65536 watches. The boot up and login process should not be using that many of them, surely?
My questions are:

Is this bad? Should I try to find a problem or just increase the number of watches and forget about it?
What's a reasonable number of watches for a modern Ubuntu system?
How do I find out what program(s) is/are using all the watches?

I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
